# How to create a single progress line using Apache eCharts?

Tags: echarts

How do I create a single progress line using Apache eCharts?

Here is in an image example:

[image]

The green line should change depending on it's value, for example:

- When the value is 10 there should only be a small green line.
- When the value is 50 the green should fill half the line, and grey the other half.
- When the value is 100 it should be all green.

The green line should also animate on load.

It should have rounded end caps.

And it should resize based on the width of the container.

Is this simple type of progress line possible in Apache eCharts?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go : ([my echarts sandbox](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graphic-loading&code=G4QwTgBADmD2DmYCmBnFAZAlgOyep28ALgBYQC8EArAAw0DcAUKJALYgAeAaiADYCuSChACMdJiwigBQygHYGjRrChFMsbMIDejCBEQgoJTAGMAXBB169SXklYEiKCwG1d1vVY_WiATyhIFgDkiLD8UEEANO7eEHYAZkTBJo5IYFEx3kQqyanp0bF6Jsa8ACbI2K6ZsV6FPv6BEEHIJkQZdR4oJIaNtR16HGY0Bf3WvkMjoxAA7pilpBYwCMhoWLj4hKSToyRImPAkSWLbdQC-J4UofnYWff3xmLy8wQDEAKJUHx9B1YWnvx5zgDrHdCn4AsEWm0LrEuj1bsDYoNhojvOMUVM9LN5iRFnBEKgMDg8ARiCQAFTSQQAenY3D4ghhhV2-0OZmOqL0QKmV18N0snOsDyerwAzAAOOQAFgAwgAhH5TbmjADWSF88TAIAcAEFsJh2GoNAjMRBSvwtUbKqI6BjMbxYDkIPE-CgkEzYmqNVqHM4IG5TaD-gEwClsEkIHbTSgTHwkAANCxR0bKqZBjohsMRkQey6xuyJ0S5wEQQV6AC6gv-_WrhUrsVrFfc_1O9CAA))

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var progressLineLength = 500;
var maxValue = 100;
var value = 70;

option = {
  graphic: {
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'group',
        left: 'center',
        top: 'center',
        children: [
          {
            type: 'rect',
            shape: {
              x:0,
              y:0,
              width: progressLineLength,
              height:10,
            },
            style: {
              fill: '#E5E5E5'
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'rect',
            shape: {
              x:0,
              y:0,
              width: progressLineLength*value/maxValue,
              height:10,
            },
            style: {
              fill: '#3874CB'
            },
            keyframeAnimation: {
              duration: 1000,
              loop: false,
              keyframes: [
              {
                percent: 0,
                scaleX: 0,
              },
              {
                percent: 1,
                scaleX: 1,
              } 
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! But actually I just realized I also need round end caps on the lines. Is that possible? I have updated the question to say this also.

Comment: In addition to that it seems this is not able to resize when the screen shrinks down. The grey bar disappears on smaller screens. Makes me think maybe `graphic` is not the right choice here. Is there another graph type that would work?